# Appcelerator ti.storekit invalid product

Tags: ios, appcelerator-titanium, storekit, appcelerator-mobile

I am getting Invalid Product error when I am requesting a product.

Here is the full error

```
[INFO] :   {
[INFO] :       invalid =     (
[INFO] :           "<Product>"
[INFO] :       );
[INFO] :       products =     (
[INFO] :       );
[INFO] :       source = "[object TiStorekitProductRequest]";
[INFO] :       success = 1;
[INFO] :       type = callback;
[INFO] :   }
```

I am using 6.0.1 SDK and iOS version is 10.2

I am running and testing on my iPhone 6 from Appcelerator Studio (not AdHoc, just development certificate)

Here is the example that I am using

https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.storekit/blob/master/ios/example/app.js

So I have done the following

- Created product in iTunesConnect which is ready to submit
- My product Cleared checked for Sale
- I have In-App purchase in my AppId (Apple Account)
- I have Bundle Id and version in my code
- In app/assets folder I added AppleIncRootCertificate.cer
- receiptVerificationSandbox=(Ti.App.deployType !== 'production');
- My device can make payments
- My device is not jailbroken
- And I have this in my xml file

  com.apple.security.app-sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one thing I didn't complete.

My bank account details were not active in iTunes Connect.